# What is an example of a non compact convergent series of holomorphic functions which converges to holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a sequence of holomorphic function $\{f_n\}$ on a domain $D$ with limit function $f$ . It is known that if the convergence is compact (i.e. converge uniformly to $f$
in every compact subset of $D$), $f$ is holomorphic on $D$.

Then is there an example that $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ but the convergence is not compact?

**Edit**: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526809/holomorphic-functions-which-converge-pointwise-but-not-almost-uniformly) is a similar question but this doesn't answer to my question since I require $f$ to be **holomorphic**. So this is not the duplicate!

Comment: the same proof as in the duplicate works slightly modified; namely take $G$ entire nonconstant st for every fixed $t$ we have $G(re^{it})$ bounded for all $r$ (with bound depending on $t$ of course); then take $H(z)=\frac{(G(z)-G(0))^2}{z}$ so $H$ entire, $H(0)=0$ and for fixed $t$ we have $H(re^{it}) \to 0, r \to \infty$ so $H_n(z)=H(nz) \to 0, n \to \infty$; $H_n$ cannot converge uniformly around $0$ since otherwise we would have $|H_n(z)| < C$ for all $n$ and $|z|< \delta$ but this means $H$ would be bounded since every $w$ in the plane is $nz$ for some large $n$ and $|z|<\delta$